# How to specify correctly Nginx reverse proxy configuration for POST /some_endpoint/<product>/<component>/<key> using Regex

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-location

How to write properly configuration for Nginx in order to map incoming POST /some_endpoint/product/component/key to the appropriate node?
Product, component, key are different from request to request.

I have tried some variants, no lack.

```
location /some_endpoint/([0-9A-Za-z]+)$/([0-9A-Za-z]+)$/([0-9A-Za-z]+)$ {
        proxy_pass  http://first-node:8080/some_endpoint/$1/$2/$3;
  }

location /some_endpoint/(~*)$/(~*)$/(~*)$ {
        proxy_pass  http://first-node:8080/some_endpoint/$1/$2/$3;
  }
```

Comment: Why do you need a regular expression? Just use `location /some_endpoint/ { proxy_pass  http://first-node:8080; }`

Comment: We have a lot of endpoints. And would like that one subset of them will be served using first node and another subset of them will be served using second node.

Comment: Agree with @RichardSmith. If your URL path format and proxy pass server remain the same for every request, `location /some_endpoint/ { proxy_pass  http://first-node:8080; }` should work fine. 
If you have specific subsets to use 2nd node, you can have those separately with
location `location /some_endpoint/(product1|product2)/(component1|component2)/(key1|key2) { proxy_pass  http://second-node:8080; }`

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved needed behaviour using the following configurations:

```
  location ~/rest-endpoint1/(.*)$ {
    proxy_pass  http://first-node:8080/rest-endpoint1/$1$is_args$args;
}

  location ~/rest-endpoint2/(.*)$ {
    proxy_pass  http://first-node:8080/rest-endpoint2/$1$is_args$args;
}
  location ~/rest-endpoint3/(.*)$ {
    proxy_pass  http://second-node:8081/rest-endpoint3/$1$is_args$args;
}

  location ~/rest-endpoint4/(.*)$ {
    proxy_pass  http://second-node:8081/rest-endpoint4/$1$is_args$args;
}
```